# does kakfka-console-consumer consumes from multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic with multiple partitions.

I want to dump the topic into a file to conduct some analysis there, therefore i think the easiest way to do it is to use the kafka-console-consumer.

My question is, does the kafka-console-consumer is able to read to all the topic partitions, or it will be assigned to a single partition?

If not, how do assign the kafka-console-consumer to a specific partition, therefore a would have to start as many kafka-console-consumers as partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, kafka-console-consumer reads from all available partitions. Also take a look at [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat), it has some more advanced but usefull features.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned by Lukas, you can use kafkacat to dump all messages from a topic to a local file:

```
kafkacat -b a_broker -t your_topic -o beginning > all_msgs.bin
```

This will consume messages from all partitions, if you want to limit to a single partition use the `-p <partition>` switch.

The default output message separator is newline (\n), if you want something else use the `-f "<fmt>"` option.